# Windows 10 Authentication Provider Setup

Tags: windows, authentication, credential-providers

Can anybody point out to me how I can enable Windows 10 to display multiple Authentication Providers? For some reason, I am not able to see the "Switch Users" button on the login screen.

I do understand that there are options to change authentication providers in the system registry and gpedit.msc. However, any changes I make seem to not make a difference and the default userid/password login keeps displaying. I can disable the default userid/login but nothing else comes up as a choice if I have it enabled.

Does Windows 10 work like Windows 7 in this regard or is it completely different? I have been able to get it to work on Windows 7...just not 10.

Any feedback, examples, instructions, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "Authentication Provider"? CredentialProvider? Windows 10 works a little bit different in this case. As it promotes a "user centric login experience" other credentialprovider do not appear as "other users" but as login options on the user tile.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have actually figured it out. The issue I was seeing was only occurring in a VM. My credential provider was showing up as tile on the menu just as a user login tile. Thanks for the feedback.